# Call method and access properties in a client side app from a web browser

Tags: javascript, java, client-side

We have a solution that deals with devices on Windows and would like to make calls to certain components of it from webbrowsers (Edge, chrome, firefox) by using javascript so this will be done client side.
We used to do it by using activex but since this technology works pretty much only for Iexplorer and now with modern browsers being depricated, is not an option any more. 
Our solution is Java based and also some C#.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: fact is you need a bridge. this can be every language what is able to access to the devices. c# c++ java ....  the browser alone and javascript can not handle it directly without any kind of api in the background. to access the api you simply can use ajax

Comment: So in the old way where we were using activex, that was the bridge? with activex we had some entries in the windows registry (classes) and all we had to do was to reference those classes in javascript and make the calls needed.

Comment: yes, you used activex as plugin in your browser so that was the bridge to the hardware. but it's deprecated ;)

Comment: Do you know a bridge techology I could use to expose my component to all modern browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399578/are-there-alternatives-for-activex-in-microsoft-edge sorry, use search engines for find this answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the way to go by using Native messaging. I'll give it a try and will write the results.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only way to do that would be to create a web service that exposes your components, then make web requests to that service from JavaScript. That is all any modern browser will allow you to do.

Comment: This means the web service will be hosted on every machine where we will need it, right?

Comment: No, the best solution would be to have a single web service.

Comment: But since the webservice will have to deal with devices connected to every single machine, I believe that web service needs to be installed right there in every machine.

Answer (score 0):

We are investigating another oprtion that seems feasible, using websockets seems to be more reliable than using native messaging since the lastone relies too much on browser version and would involve the creation of an extension for at least three browsers, edge, chrome and firefox and if something changes in those browsers it would probably breaks the extension. While with websockets this wont happend.

Has enyone have done something similar?