# After browser stopped supporting activex and npapi, what is the replacement for activex and npapi

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find alternate to activex and npapi technology to develop plugin for browsers

Comment: There's no direct replacement so the closest thing is extensions + [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to launch an external program where your advanced processing can be done and communicate with it.

Comment: I agree for the suggestion about Native messaging. You can also try to refer this thread may give you some more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399578/are-there-alternatives-for-activex-in-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging to solve my issue. This helped my implementation